# Having TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras

I'm getting the following error on the mentioned lines inside the code:

> TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Please someone resolve this issue. Removal of parenthesis didn't help, another error pops up stating:

> IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean)
> type

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow.keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


n_pts = 500
np.random.seed(0)
Xa = np.array([np.random.normal(13, 2, n_pts), <*Type error encountered here*>
           np.random.normal(12, 2, n_pts)]).T
Xb = np.array([np.random.normal(8, 2, n_pts),
           np.random.normal(6, 2, n_pts)]).T

X = np.vstack((Xa, Xb))
y = np.matrix(np.append(np.zeros(n_pts), np.ones(n_pts))).T

plt.scatter(X[:n_pts,0], X[:n_pts,1])
plt.scatter(X[n_pts:,0], X[n_pts:,1])

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units = 1, input_shape = (2,), activation = 'sigmoid'))
adam = Adam(lr = 0.1)
model.compile(adam, loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics= ['accuracy'])
h = model.fit(x = X, y = y, verbose = 1, batch_size = 50, epochs = 500, shuffle = 'true')

plt.plot(h.history['accuracy'])
plt.title('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['accuracy'])

plt.plot(h.history['loss'])
plt.title('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['loss'])

def plot_decision_boundary(X,y, model):
    x_span = np.linspace(min(X[:,0]) - 1, max(X[:, 0]) + 1)
    y_span = np.linspace(min(X[:,1]) - 1, max(X[:, 0]) + 1)
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x_span, y_span)
    xx_, yy_ = xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()
    grid = np.c_[xx_, yy_]
    pred_func = model.predict(grid)
    z = pred_func.reshape(xx.shape)
    plt.contourf(xx,yy, z)


plot_decision_boundary(X, y , model)
plt.scatter(X[:n_pts, 0], X[:n_pts,1])
plt.scatter(X[n_pts:,0], X[n_pts:,1])
x = 7.5 
y = 5
point = np.array([[x,y]])
prediction = model.predict(point)
plt.plot([x],[y], marker="o", markersize=10, color="red")  
print("Prediction", prediction)
```

Comment: I have run this code on my machine, everything working fine. The final prediction is: `Prediction [[0.9999958]]`.

Comment: I run the code on google colab TPU, and it run without any error; Of course by removing just `<*Type error encountered here*>`  from the code.

Comment: Works fine for me too. I tried executing it on Google Colab running on CPU